# Why does Gulp-Bundle task complain about wrong configuration with Gulp v4?

Tags: javascript, gulp

How is it possible..?
I tried to create a bundle task with the package called [gulp-bundle-assets](https://github.com/dowjones/gulp-bundle-assets) but it doesn't work. This is the sample-config from the documentation with my files which I wanna bundle...

If I try `gulp bundle` the console says:

> Configuration file should be in the form "{ bundle: {}, copy: {} }"

```
// bundle.config.js
module.exports = {
    bundle: {
        main: {
            styles: './content/**/*.css',
        },
        vendor: {
            scripts: [
                './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                './node_modules/instafeed.js/instafeed.js',
                './node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js',
            ],
        },
    },
    copy: './assets/**/*.{png,svg}',
};
```

My gulp task looks like:

```
// gulpfile.js
gulp.task('bundle', function() {
    return gulp.src('./bundle.config.js')
        .pipe(bundle())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});
```

My versions:

- npm v6.4.0
- node v10.6.0
- gulp v4.0.0
- gulp-bundle-assets v2.29.0

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Seems, it is an unresolved dependency issue. See here: https://github.com/dowjones/gulp-bundle-assets/issues/114